# Why does this MD5 Matlab implementation break down for certain message sizes?

Tags: matlab, md5

The following is an M-file for generating an MD5 digest on a file of ASCII values. I have a string of HEX values and am converting it to ASCII, then writing these values to a file which I pass to the md5 function. I am using two different online MD5 calculators to validate the script's solution. [Here is one of them.](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm)

The method by which I am converting from HEX string to ACSII is by pairing two hex values and then converting the pairs to ASCII chars which are then written to the file. I know this is being done correctly because I can pass either the HEX string to the above mentioned online calculators or upload their equivalent ASCII representation and they produce the same (valid) result even though the MATLAB script gives the wrong digest.

For some reason, whether the digest is computed correctly or not depends on the number of ASCII values being read from the file. I've tried to understand if there is any pattern to this behavior but I cannot find any. It produces a valid digest for messages with 200,300-to-322, 500,996,998,1008,1010,1050,1070,1076 HEX characters which are first converted to the ASCII file. But not for 1000,1002,1004,1006,1078,1100 HEX characters. In short, I see no method to this madness... any help would be much appreciated.

```
    % md5   Compute MD5 hash function for files
%
%   d = md5(FileName)
%
%   md5() computes the MD5 hash function of
%   the file specified in the string FileName
%   and returns it as a 64-character array d.


%   The MD5 message-digest algorithm is specified
%   in RFC 1321.

%  The code below is for instructional and illustrational
%  purposes only. It is very clear, but very slow.

% (C) Stefan Stoll, ETH Zurich, 2006

function Digest = md5(FileName)

% Guard against old Matlab versions
MatlabVersion = version;
if MatlabVersion(1)<'7'
  error('md5() requires Matlab 7.0 or later!');
end

% Run autotest if no parameters are given
if (nargin==0)
  md5autotest;
  return;
end

% Read in entire file into uint32 vector
[Message,nBits] = readmessagefromfile(FileName);
%--------------------------------------------------

% Append a bit-1 to the last bit read from file
BytesInLastInt = mod(nBits,32)/8;
if BytesInLastInt
  Message(end) = bitset(Message(end),BytesInLastInt*8+8);
else
  Message = [Message; uint32(128)];
end

% Append zeros
nZeros = 16 - mod(numel(Message)+2,16);
Message = [Message; zeros(nZeros,1,'uint32')];

% Append bit length of original message as uint64, lower significant uint32 first
Lower32 = uint32(nBits);
Upper32 = uint32(bitshift(uint64(nBits),-32));
Message = [Message; Lower32; Upper32];

%--------------------------------------------------

% 64-element transformation array
T = uint32(fix(4294967296*abs(sin(1:64))));

% 64-element array of number of bits for circular left shift
S = repmat([7 12 17 22; 5 9 14 20; 4 11 16 23; 6 10 15 21].',4,1);
S = S(:).';

% 64-element array of indices into X
idxX  = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 ...
         1 6 11 0 5 10 15 4 9 14 3 8 13 2 7 12 ...
         5 8 11 14 1 4 7 10 13 0 3 6 9 12 15 2 ...
         0 7 14 5 12 3 10 1 8 15 6 13 4 11 2 9] + 1;

% Initial state of buffer (consisting of A, B, C and D)
A = uint32(hex2dec('67452301'));
B = uint32(hex2dec('efcdab89'));
C = uint32(hex2dec('98badcfe'));
D = uint32(hex2dec('10325476'));

%--------------------------------------------------

Message = reshape(Message,16,[]);

% Loop over message blocks each 16 uint32 long
for iBlock = 1:size(Message,2)

  % Extract next block
  X = Message(:,iBlock);

  % Store current buffer state
  AA = A;
  BB = B;
  CC = C;
  DD = D;

  % Transform buffer using message block X and the
  % parameters from S, T and idxX
  k = 0;
  for iRound = 1:4
    for q = 1:4
      A = Fun(iRound,A,B,C,D,X(idxX(k+1)),S(k+1),T(k+1));
      D = Fun(iRound,D,A,B,C,X(idxX(k+2)),S(k+2),T(k+2)); 
      C = Fun(iRound,C,D,A,B,X(idxX(k+3)),S(k+3),T(k+3)); 
      B = Fun(iRound,B,C,D,A,X(idxX(k+4)),S(k+4),T(k+4)); 
      k = k + 4;
    end
  end

  % Add old buffer state
  A = bitadd32(A,AA);
  B = bitadd32(B,BB);
  C = bitadd32(C,CC);
  D = bitadd32(D,DD);

end

%--------------------------------------------------

% Combine uint32 from buffer to form message digest
Str = lower(dec2hex([A;B;C;D]));
Str = Str(:,[7 8 5 6 3 4 1 2]).';
Digest = Str(:).';

%==================================================

function y = Fun(iRound,a,b,c,d,x,s,t)
switch iRound
case 1
  q = bitor(bitand(b,c),bitand(bitcmp(b),d));
case 2
  q = bitor(bitand(b,d),bitand(c,bitcmp(d)));
case 3
  q = bitxor(bitxor(b,c),d);
case 4
  q = bitxor(c,bitor(b,bitcmp(d)));
end
y = bitadd32(b,rotateleft32(bitadd32(a,q,x,t),s));

%--------------------------------------------

function y = rotateleft32(x,s)
y = bitor(bitshift(x,s),bitshift(x,s-32));

%--------------------------------------------

function sum = bitadd32(varargin)
sum = varargin{1};
for k = 2:nargin
  add = varargin{k};
  carry = bitand(sum,add);
  sum = bitxor(sum,add);
  for q = 1:32
    shift = bitshift(carry,1);
    carry = bitand(shift,sum);
    sum = bitxor(shift,sum);
  end
end

function [Message,nBits] = readmessagefromfile(FileName)
[hFile,ErrMsg] = fopen(FileName,'r');
error(ErrMsg);
%Message = fread(hFile,inf,'bit32=>uint32');
Message = fread(hFile,inf,'ubit32=>uint32');
%Message = fread(hFile);
fclose(hFile);
d = dir(FileName);
nBits = d.bytes*8;

%============================================

function md5autotest

disp('Running md5 autotest...');

Messages{1} = '';
Messages{2} = 'a';
Messages{3} = 'abc';
Messages{4} = 'message digest';
Messages{5} = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
Messages{6} = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
Messages{7} = char(128:255);

CorrectDigests{1} = 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e';
CorrectDigests{2} = '0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661';
CorrectDigests{3} = '900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72';
CorrectDigests{4} = 'f96b697d7cb7938d525a2f31aaf161d0';
CorrectDigests{5} = 'c3fcd3d76192e4007dfb496cca67e13b';
CorrectDigests{6} = 'd174ab98d277d9f5a5611c2c9f419d9f';
CorrectDigests{7} = '16f404156c0500ac48efa2d3abc5fbcf';

TmpFile = tempname;
for k=1:numel(Messages)
  [h,ErrMsg] = fopen(TmpFile,'w');
  error(ErrMsg);
  fwrite(h,Messages{k},'char');
  fclose(h);
  Digest = md5(TmpFile);
  fprintf('%d: %s\n',k,Digest);
  if ~strcmp(Digest,CorrectDigests{k})
    error('md5 autotest failed on the following string: %s',Messages{k});
  end
end
delete(TmpFile);
disp('md5 autotest passed!');
```

Comment: Please include an example file, which causes the problems.

Comment: On my machine the self test fails because the reference value is wrong. According to unix md5sum it should be `CorrectDigests{7} = '946c295284edb33cb8a62bed8120c9f1'`

Comment: I will provide an example file for both successful and unsuccessful digests tomorrow. Strangely enough the self test doesn't fail on the computer I've been using. But the digest you've posted is correct and confirmed by the online calculator. Yet the script's self test gives an incorrect answer and if I manually write to a file using data = char(128:255) --> fwrite(fopen('text.txt','wt'),data) --> md5('test.txt') I get Digest = 16f404156c0500ac48efa2d3abc5fbcf

Comment: The example failed on my machine because it was written unicode. After setting a charset at fopen the example worked fine. Maybe different char encodings cause your issues as well?

Comment: Very interesting. Setting it to UTF-8 caused the auto-test to fail but it produced the correct digest. Hopefully this will fix the message size issue I am seeing. Thank you!

Comment: I went through and made sure that charset for my code's fwrite and the script's fread are both 'UTF-8'. Now I have agreement between the online calculator's digest IF I upload the same file that I'm passing to the script. But I do not get the same digest on the calculator if I pass the message as HEX data. There must be some correct charset for this conversion. This is the file I'm using
http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=14527614602339339159
I'd post the HEX data but it's too long.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite old, but I looked through the code and I think that you are not handling the message length properly.  I also found some issues with way that certain maths were done in MatLAB differently - for instance bitshifting was not used as I had expected, and also integer maths of uint32 variables not always handled the way you'd expect. You need to handle modular math and truncating math manually/explicitly or read the help documents a little more closely regarding those topics. Also, check the character base in your options, char128:255 might not be translating correctly, try using the command to create the message and then paste it into a different interface. Even in matlab if you process that variable even once it will get messed up bad, it comes out as ???????????yadda yadda. If you were using decimal maths you might have introduced an epsilon error as well, but check out the actual length...